# Receive and send messages between client and server with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, server, client

I was wondering in the simplest way how to send a message to all clients, then when the client clicks the message it sends back a different message back to the server.

I realise inside the ../www file for PhoneGap you need to have 2 different JavaScript files, one being index which is client? and another one for server?

I don't really know where to start with the server code either, like how it extends into the client code.

If anyone could help me out in any way or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do u want to do exactly  ????

Comment: I want to be able to send a link to all users and when the users click the link, I get a message back saying that they clicked it.

Comment: Then send a push notification to all the users, and assign a click function to the link, when the user click on the link make an ajax call to send acknowledgement.